# How to check if <NA> type variable is <NA> or not from a pandas dataframe? np.nan() not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe with a column whose values look something like:

```
     YEAR_TORONTO
0    <NA>
1    2016
2    <NA>
3    1999
```

I need to check each element of this dataframe individually via a `for` loop for other reasons outside this segment of code, so I'm looking for solutions that comply with my implementation.

Essentially the code I have at the moment to check the presence of  is:

```
if np.isnan(df.get("YEAR_TORONTO")[row]):
```

This leads to me getting the following error for the `<NA>` values:

```
boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Any idea of what I can do to fix this error? Help much appreciated

Comment: `pd.isna()`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html

Comment: `pd.NA` is not really `np.nan`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As sammywemmy said, `pd.isna()` should work.

```
>>> d = pd.Series([1,2,pd.NA,3])
>>> d
0       1
1       2
2    <NA>
3       3
dtype: object
>>> d.isna()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```